# Reading from config.file throws FileNotFoundException (no such file or directory)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ioexception, configuration-files

this is my project structure

```
- src
-- java
--- utils
---- ConfigFileReader
--- resources
---- config.properties
```

this is **ConfigFileReader** class:

```
public class ConfigFileReader {

    public static String getProperty(String key) {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("/config.properties");
            properties.load(inputStream);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return properties.getProperty(key);
    }
}
```

and this is my **config.properties** file:

```
account_storage_technology=cognito
```

Unfortunately executing that method throws

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /config.properties (No such file or directory)

- How can I fix?

Comment: try reading it as `ConfigFileReader.class.getResourceAsStream("/config.properties")`

Comment: it returns null

Comment: will not work ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep the `resources` folder in the same level as `src`. Like this:

```
- src
 - java
  - utils
    - ConfigFileReader
- resources
  - config.properties
```

And modify the path as below :

```
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("resources/config.properties");
```

**UPDATE** :  It is not advisable or a good idea to keep properties files inside packages and read it from there. However you can make your code read the file by showing the absolute full path.

Example :

```
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("C:\\Project-Path\\Project-Name\\src\\java\\resources\\config.properties");

// Project-Path : This is the path where your Project Parent folder resides.
// Project-Name : This is the name of your project.
```

Comment: resources packages is alongside with java package by default

Comment: @user14021516  :  This is not a very good design to read properties file from packages which are intended only for keeping java classes. In that case you need to give the absolute path for the `config.properties` file. It will work though, let me update my answer.

Comment: That worked... where should I put my config.properties file instead of resource package (generated by default)?

Comment: If not present already , create a folder as "resources" in the same level as the "src" folder. And keep all your configuration related files inside that. This is the way.

Comment: @user14021516  : Good to know that worked, If this worked for you can  you pls accept my answer and upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

when you do '/' in the begining it will try to read from your root directory. Remove the / and as long as the config.properties is present in src/main/resources, the FileInputStream should be able to pick the config file.

```
ConfigFileReader.class.getResourceAsStream("config.properties")
```